# Symfony form from child class does not load choice options

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, formbuilder

In the formtype:

```
$builder
    ->add('tarifaReexpedicion', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:SubtarifaReexpedicion',
        'label' => false,
        'choice_label' => 'nombre',
        'placeholder' => 'Elige una subtarifa...',
    ));
```

In the parent class `Subtarifa` there is an attribute called `nombre`, with getName and setName... everything right.
The child class is `SubtarifaReexpedicion`.

In this code when I change `'class' => 'AppBundle:Subtarifa'` everything works fine and it loads all the options (all, not the specific options of that subclass).

The configuration for the parent Entity (Subtarifa):

```
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="subtarifas")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"FLETE" = "SubtarifaFlete", "REEXP" = "SubtarifaReexpedicion", "MASALLA" = "SubtarifaMasalla"})
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
->add('tarifaReexpedicion', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:SubtarifaReexpedicion',
    'label' => false,
    'choice_label' => 'nombre',
    'placeholder' => 'Elige una subtarifa...',
));
```

you are using AppBundle:SubtarifaReexpedicion entity and your desired choice_label is `nombre`, so make sure that there is `getNombre()` method in the `AppBundle:SubtarifaReexpedicion` class.

The `choice_label` basically calls the callback as if you do it this way:

```
'choice_label' => function ($tarifaReexpedicion) {
    return $tarifaReexpedicion->getNombre();
}
```